# APK Analyzer: There were problems loading: usage.txt

Tags: android, proguard

APK Analyzer successfully loaded maps from: mapping.txt,seeds.txt
            **There were problems loading: usage.txt**

There is no any reference about that problem anywhere. How to find the problem?
the file generated and openning normally but not loading

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

I removed everything from rules.pro

```
-printseeds build/outputs/mapping/release/seeds.txt
-printusage build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

same result! any ideas?